# Cloudsim Physical Machine Creation

Tags: virtual-machine, cloudsim

Is it possible to create a new physical machine in the VmAllocationPolicy file? Usually it is done while creating datacenter.But i wanted to add one during VM Allocation if none of the existing Physical machine can accommodate the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a new Host dynamically after creation.

```
datacenter.getHostList().add(new Host(...));
```